# What are differences between Dnyaneshwari and other Bhagavad Gita commentaries?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, philosophy

Dnyaneshwari (IAST:'Jñānēśvarī) is a commentary on the Bhagavad Gita, written by the great Saint Sant Dnyaneshwar in Marathi. It's considered to be the best scripture in Marathi literature.

What ideas are in the Dnyaneshwari which are not in other commentaries on the Bhagavad Gita?